# Parameters on Columns that populates the next parameter values SQL\SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

What I am try to get is when a user hits the report they choose which Column the want to use as a filter and then that gets passed to the next parameter to list the values for the they can choose from.

made up table: 
 
Device         Software
fs01           Apple
fs01           pear
fs01           orange
fs01           peach
fs01           bannana
fs01           peanuts
fs02           Apple
fs02           pear
fs02           orange
fs02           peach
fs02           bannana
fs02           peanuts

They would be able to choose either  Device or Software(Parameter1) then lets say they choose "Device" for the first parameter the second parameter would then show the distinct values for "Device". Or Choose "software"(Parameter1) and it would show the distinct values for "software" for the second parameter.

Sorry kinda of new to this.

Answer (score 0):

This is called cascading parameters.  I could explain how to do it, but there are already so many other examples out there.

Please follow the example at:
http://100rov.blogspot.com/2013/02/add-cascading-parameters-to-report.html

or at Microsoft's site:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337498(v=sql.105).aspx